# using sed and grep to erase html

Tags: search, sed

i have a code like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>some normal html code</div>
<!--f1930e-->
some javascript code goes here...
<!--/f1930e-->

some other html....
</body>
</html>
```

how do i remove the part of:

```
<!--f1930e-->
some javascript code goes here...
<!--/f1930e-->
```

so that it become:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>some normal html code</div>
some other html....
</body>
</html>
```

my command is like this:

```
grep -lr -e 'f1930e' * | xargs sed -e 's/<!--f1930e-->.*<!--\/f1930e-->//'
```

that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
$ sed '/<!--f1930e-->/,/<!--\/f1930e-->/d' file.html
<html>
<body>
<div>some normal html code</div>

some other html....
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to really modify the file, add the `-i` switch to [sed](/questions/tagged/sed).